# Add sequence number to the listbox items retrieved by SqlDataReader ()

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, listboxitems

I have little problem I am trying to add sequenced numbers in front the data that I will retrieve from a SQL Server database as shown below.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.;database=test;integrated security=false;user id=sa;pwd=@admin00");
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();

    SqlDataReader dr;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        com.CommandText = "select book_name from Table_book";
        com.Connection = con;
        con.Open();

        dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dr.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(i+"-"+dr[0].ToString());
                i += i;
            }
        }

        if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Data Found");            
        }

        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
```

And the result will be like that:

[image]

**TY all**

Comment: Why not use server side sequence number? It should simplify your code and make results more consistent. Check this out: [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms186734.aspx). It is a partition function, but you can omit partitioning and just specify ORDER BY, see examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use my server Id sequence to solve the problem like that:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=.;database=test;integrated security=false;user id=sa;pwd=@admin00");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("select book_id,book_name from Table_book", con);
        SqlDataReader sqlDR=sqlcom.ExecuteReader();
        while(sqlDR.Read())
        {
        listBox1.Items.Add(sqlDR["book_id"].ToString()+"-"+sqlDR["book_name"].ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Add` is capable of operating on objects, not just on strings. 
Why?

```
class ModelClass {

   // for use in algorithm, may be presented in GUI or not
   int Sequence { get; set; }

   string Description { get ; set ;}
   // ... what You want, is is typical model class

   override string ToString() { 
    // return what you want, is presented in GUI
    return Descrition; 
   }
   ModelClass( string n, int i ) ... 
}
 ...

  listBox.Items.Add( new ModelClass(i.ToString(), dr[...] // sequence )
```

Now you can check whatever you want from Items, because these are objects of ModelClass.

Code written by hand, non tested in IDE.

Answer (score -1):

You're setting the "sequence number" to the number of *fields* returned in the results while iterating over each row with the `dr.Read()`. 
It's unnecessary for the `for` loop.  What you should be doing is setting your counter variable outside of the `dr.Read()` and then incrementing it inside...

```
int i = 1;
while (dr.Read())
{ 
    // set listbox item text
    listBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString() + "-" + dr[0].ToString());
     i+=1;
}
```

Comment: This give me That error index out of range exception was unhandled

Comment: Its giving error to me also because only one time that is first time when we go in that while loop we all data of all field counts. so we need to use for loop inside while loop...